# How to deploy varnish on aks/gke/eks?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks, azure-aks, varnish

I am trying to create a scalable varnish cluster on some managed Kubernetes services (azure's, google's,  or amazon's Kubernetes service)  but I'm having trouble getting started. Any advice or references are helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We (Varnish Software) are working on official Helm charts to make k8s deployments a lot easier. For the time being we only have an official Docker Image.

You can find install instructions on https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/running-varnish-docker/.

However, I have some standalone k8s files that can be a good way to get started.

### Config map

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: varnish
  labels:
    name: varnish
data:
  default.vcl: |+
    vcl 4.1;
    backend default none;
    
    sub vcl_recv {
        if (req.url == "/varnish-ping") {
            return(synth(200));
        }
    
        if (req.url == "/varnish-ready") {
            return(synth(200));
        }

        return(synth(200,"Welcome"));
    }
```

This config map contains the VCL file. This VCL file doesn't do anything useful besides having `/varnish-ping` & `/varnish-ready` endpoints. Please customize to your needs.

### Service definition

Here's a basic service definition that exposes port `80`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: varnish
  labels:
    name: varnish
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
      name: varnish-http
  selector:
    name: varnish
```

### Deployment

And finally here's the deployment. It uses the official Varnish Docker image and more specifically the *6.0 LTS version*.

It uses the synthetic `/varnish-ping` & `/varnish-ready` endpoints and mounts the config map under `/etc/varnish` to load the VCL file.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: varnish
  labels:
    name: varnish
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: varnish
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: varnish
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: varnish
          image: "varnish:stable"
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /varnish-ping
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 5
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /varnish-ready
              port: 80
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 5
          volumeMounts:
          - name: varnish
            mountPath: /etc/varnish
      volumes:
      - name: varnish
        configMap:
          name: varnish
```

### Deploying the config

Run `kubectl apply -f .` in the folder with the various k8s files (config map, service definition & deployment). This is the output you'll get:

```
$ kubectl apply -f .
configmap/varnish created
deployment.apps/varnish created
service/varnish created
```

By running `kubectl get all` you'll see the status of the deployment.

When running this on your local computer, just call `kubectl port-forward service/varnish 8080:80` to port forward the Varnish service to `localhost:8080`. This allows you to test Varnish on k8s locally by accessing `http://localhost:8080`.

Run `kubectl delete -f .` to tear it down again.

### Disclaimer

Although these configs were featured in my [Varnish 6 by Example](https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/varnish-6-by-example-book/) book, this is not an official tutorial. These scripts can probably be improved. However, it is a simple way to get started.

Comment: Hi, I did this and I wasn't able to connect to the IP address, and when I checked there was no external IP address. What is the outcome of a successfully deployed varnish cluster?

Comment: You should probably configure the ingress to have HTTP connectivity to the outside world. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/ to learn about ingress in general. Using ingress you can connect your Ingress Controller to the Varnish service that was defined.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Varnish on Kubernetes [operator](https://github.com/mittwald/kube-httpcache).